# SSRS Sub Report repeats the header after each row.

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, bids

Im having a problem with SSRS reports. I have a subreport that I have made:[image: This is the subreport]

its a simple enough table but the problem is when I preview it I get a repeating header after each row:

[image]

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Is the subreport appearing multiple times in the parent report?  If so, this may be the cause of the repetitions

Comment: No it only appears once in the report and it only shows up once. The table is not in the report after that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe "group header" with column names have been added to the table.

The easiest way to fix:

1. Add new Row outside the group (if it does not exist)
2. Add column names in the new row created in step 1
3. Delete group header names from group.

[image]

Comment: Yes this is the problem. Thank you!